# eclipse regular expression search

Tags: regex, eclipse

What is the correct regular expression to `Find a string that begins with "Bla", followed by any chars, followed by the string " = new " followed by anything, such as "Bla myNewBla = new Bla();"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
Bla.* = new .*
```

Comment: yup! worked! tks alot! lol i can only accept your answer in 10 min!

Comment: Actually I missed the `=` character in the regex, just to be more aligned with the constructor syntax. Updated the post.